# Why external function can't navigate other javascript file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making simple app which contains Todo App.
However, the function which locate in outside of main function(Is this expression right?) in same Javascript file can't navigate to other screen.

Below is my Screen structure(simplified)

```
<Stack.Screen name="Myqtwrite" component={MyqtwriteScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
<Stack.Screen name="Myqtupdate" component={MyqtupdateScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
```

And the problem is below.
I expressed the location of problem.

MyqtwriteScreen.js

```
export function Note(props, {navigation, route}) {
return (
    <View style={[styles.myblock, {backgroundColor:props.val.color}]}>
        <View style={{alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
            <View style={{borderBottomWidth:2,borderColor:'white',marginBottom:5}}>
                <Text style={[styles.myblocktitle]}>{props.val.date}</Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.myblocktext}>{props.val.note}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{width: '100%' ,flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'flex-end'}}>
/* problem is here-->  */   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Myqtupdate') }} style={{marginTop:5,marginLeft:10}} >
                <Text style={styles.myblockbuttontext}>UPDATE</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.deleteMethod} style={{marginTop:5,marginLeft:10}} >
                <Text style={styles.myblockbuttontext}>DELETE</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
);

}

export function MyqtwriteScreen({ navigation, route }) {

const [noteArray, setNoteArray] = useState([]);
const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState('');

let rdcolor = 'hsl('+Math.random()*255+','+ Math.random()*(60)+10+'%, 82%)';

let notes = noteArray.map((val, key) => {
    console.log('start');
    return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
        deleteMethod={() => deleteNote(key)} />
});
const addNote = () => {
    if (noteText) {
        var d = new Date();
        noteArray.unshift({
            'date': d.getFullYear() +
                "Y " + (d.getMonth() + 1) +
                "월 " + d.getDate() + "일 " + d.getHours() + "시 " + d.getMinutes()+"분",
            'note': noteText,
            'color': rdcolor,
        });
        setNoteArray(noteArray);
        setNoteText('');
        // alert('큐티 입력을 완료했습니다.');
    }
    else {
        alert('큐티를 입력하세요');
    }
};
const deleteNote = (key) => {
    const newArray = [...noteArray];
    newArray.splice(key, 1);
    setNoteArray(newArray);
};

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topbar}>
            <Text style={styles.topbartext}>오늘의 큐티</Text>
            <Icon style={styles.topbarmenu} name="close" onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('My') }} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.qtinputblock}>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={(noteText) => setNoteText(noteText)}
                value={noteText}
                placeholder='큐티를 입력하세요'
                placeholderTextColor='gray'
                multiline={true}
                style={styles.qtinputtext}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={addNote} style={styles.myblockbutton}>
                <Text style={styles.myblockbuttontext}>추가</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
            <View style={{alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
                {notes}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>



    </View>
);


}
```

I made 'MyqtupdateScreen.js' file of course.

The most interesting thing is that when I wrote same ***onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Myqtupdate') }}*** in some TouchableOpacity in the 'function MyqtwriteScreen({navigation, route'})' , it works!!
I don't understand why navigation.navigate('Myqtupdate') doesn't work in export function Note, but works in export function MyqtwriteScreen.

Any words would be help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note doesnt get a navigation prop you will have to pass it like below

```
 return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val} navigation={navigation} deleteMethod={() => deleteNote(key)} />
```

It works on the other screen as its part of the stack.

You can also use the useNavigation hook to get access to navigation.